# Как в python сделать шанс выпадения?

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Например шанс выигрыша равно 35% а проигрыш оставшиеся 75%, как сделать эти шансы?

Comment: `if random.random() < 0.35: print('Выиграл')`

Comment: Чуров, перелогинься. 35 и 75 в сумме дают 110 %

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
r = random.randint(1, 100)
If r >= 75:
    print(f'Ты проиграл, твой шанс: {r}') 
elif r <= 35:
    print(f'Ты выиграл, твой шанс: {r]}')
```

Даже запариваться не надо что бы это решить, если не ошибаюсь то можно даже одной строкой через lambda решить.
P.s. вопрос не понятный

Comment: Вопрос вполне понятный, просто должно было быть 25 и 75 процентов (или 35 и 65), и проверка нужна одна (например, если меньше 35, то выиграл, иначе проиграл). У вас получается еще "серая зона" между 35 и 75 - ни проиграл, ни выиграл

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
f = random.randint(1, 100)
c = 100 - f
print(str(f) + "% выйгрыш, " + str(c) + "% пройгрыш.")
```

Comment: Процент выйгрыша и проигрыша должен быть фиксированным, у вас же данные величины случайные.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

def probability_win(prob: float = 0.35) -> bool:
    return random.random() <= prob

chance = probability_win(0.35)
```

Если chance = True - выиграл с вероятностью 35%

Comment: if-else тут не нужен, результат `random.random() <= prob` и так равен True или False

Comment: точно, спасибо)